# Child Component and NgIf Angular 6

Tags: angular, components

i'm new in Angular 6, so i have this problem:
I have a parent component with a list of trips, i want to click on one of them and display a google map with the location of that trip. This is my parent component:

```
<div class="card ml-3 mt-3 mr-3">
    <h5 class="card-header text-white bg-info">Viajes Activos</h5>
     <div class="card-body">
         <app-trips-table [hidden]="!showTrips" (selectTrip)="selectTrip($event)"> 
        </app-trips-table>
        <app-positions *ngIf="!showTrips"></app-positions>
     </div>
</div>

selectTrip(id) {
    this.showTrips = false;  
    this.positionsComponent.putPosition(id);
  }
```

My idea is, when a user click in a trip from my parent component show the positions component and invoke a method through Viewchild to set the trip's position and initialize the google maps, but if i do this i get an error because the child component is undefined.

I hope that you would help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this trough `@ViewChild` firstly you need to define a variable you refer to in you template

```
 <app-positions *ngIf="!showTrips" #position></app-positions>
```

then when you need to get an instance of your component

`@ViewChild('position') positionsComponent: PositionsComponent;`

and after that you can write code like you does.

Same with that you can think about some better solution with `@Input` functionality.
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand  is your child view that contains a list of multiple positions.

You could use an @Output for this from your child component and use event binding on the parent component

```
// CHILD COMPONENT

export class PositionComponent {
  @Output() onPositionSelect: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  onSelect(i) {
   this.onPositionSelect.emit(i);
  }
}

// PARENT COMPONENT

<app-positions (onPositionSelect)="selectedPosition($event)"></app-positions>

export class ParentComponent {
   selectedPosition(i) {
     console.dir(i);
   }
}
```